# Error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" for Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am getting this error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I set my testing device to the simulator. However, it does work on my iPhone.

What is causing this?

Comment: we need to see more of the error log message

Answer (score 0):

- Try clearing your project `CMD + Shift + K`
- Delete derived data `Window > Projects > Derived data - Delete`
- Delete the app from your simulator